# A question about UIVIEW Tags objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, tags

I have a question about tags for UIViews.
Is it possible to create your own tag like myview.tag="main" or something like that?

I'm asking because my views are created in code and not with a nib file. After the container view has loaded and an xml file is fully parsed I need to be able to get at the subviews and update values.

After a bit of digging around I read that using viewWithTag would be a good way to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do that in your code and it is a common technique.

However, UIView-tag is an integer. So you might want to enum or define something readable
e.g. #define kMySuperViewTag 1 or enum { kMySuperViewTag, kMyNotSoSuperViewTag, ...};

Comment: hey cool, thanks.
And how do I associate the tab with a view?

Comment: myView.tag = kMySuperViewTag; //(using defines or enums as explained)

Comment: hmmmmm.....

I can access my tabbarcontroller view no problem. When I try to get at one of its sub views my apps crashes

  UITabBarController   *tabbar = nil;
 PromoTabOptionHome *home=nil;
  tabbar = (UITabBarController *)[self.view viewWithTag:79];
 home=(PromoTabOptionHome *)[tabbar.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]; //this line cause crash
 home.avatarPath=@"a test string";

Comment: Referring to your crash-problem; use the debugger:
Set a breakpoint after that tabbar=...-line. Once the debugger stopped your application, go into the GDB-console and enter: "po tabbar". Is that object actually what you expected it to be? 
If the above has no surprising results, I would guess that your tabbar does not have any subviews attached at that moment.

Comment: I figured out why it was crashing. My "PromoTabOptionHome" is actually a viewController not an actual view. I changed code to this and it worked   UITabBar   *tabbar = nil;
 UIView *home=nil;
  tabbar = (UITabBar *)[self.view viewWithTag:79];
 tabbar.alpha=0.5;
  home=(UIView *)[tabbar.subviews objectAtIndex:0];.

The problem now is I have access to the view I want but I cant access the methods in its controller like I wanted. Can I refer to the controller from some property of the view? E.G view.UIIController

Comment: Referring to your access UIViewController from inside its UIView; that is not supported by the plain UIView. If you insist on working that way you need to subclass UIView and add a reference to its UIViewController to it. Personally I find such construct not clever and would discourage its use as you were trashing reusability and creating strong dependencies on the UIView/UIViewController pairing. My rule of thumb: avoid accessing parent-objects from its childs if possible by any means. Certainly there are things were such construct makes sense but usually that is just sloppy coding.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for all of your advice. I reckon I should rethink how my code is working and do a little restructuring.

Answer (score 2):

i think you can use also something like

```
myview.layer.name="main";
```

and this field is string

Answer (score 0):

You can store pointers in the tag property of a UIView. You should cast it to an int. You should also know what to cast the tag property back to when you access it.

Example:

```
UIView * myView = [[UIView alloc] init];

myView.tag = (int)@"main";

//Later, you can access the string like so:

NSString * string = (NSString*)myView.tag;

//string now points to the string literal @"main".
```

This will probably fail with 64-bit pointers.

Comment: This is the most dangerous suggest I've ever seen. You mean to encode 4 bytes of string to integer value? Or you suggest to use a pointer address as a tag? The second one means memory leak and probably - an exception - depends on compilator. The first one - why not to use real big value that will exceed any possible subviews of superview to ensure that it is unique?

Comment: @"main" is a string literal and has a constant memory address throughout the duration of the program running. It will not change, nor will the string be released. It is not a memory leak.

Comment: Pointer as long as tag is 32/64 bits integer. @"main" has constant memory address. You are right. In any case why not to use a bitwise operator, placing 0 to youngest tag bit instead of using object for tag property that is NSInteger in its background? In your case, you compile literal, keep memory for it, use pointer to the literal. Efficiency? Same as discussing it )